# Beautifulsoup - Why it is impossible to scrape this website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The website: https://www.newamerica.org/events/?period=past

I'm trying to fyi it's **scrape** the event names and URLs. But the only output when I run the codes is: "Finished in 1.7 seconds." Nothing more. I think it might be because the events are loaded after a while when you open the page, not immediately, but it's just a guess. What can I do to solve the problem?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
import requests

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.``3945.88 Safari/537.37"
url = "https://www.newamerica.org/events/?period=past"
data = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": user_agent})
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")

document = Document()

events = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "card__text")

for event in events:
    event_name = event.find("span")
    link = event.find("a")
    try:
        print(event_name.text)
        document.add_paragraph(event_name.text, style='List Bullet')
        print(link['href'])
        document.add_paragraph(link['href'])
    except:
        continue

document.save('demo.docx')
```

Comment: ...guess the page is heavily javascript and when you get the page it is not fully rendered but keep some information in <script> tag(s) encoded as json form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page loads it's data from an API. You can make a request to that API endpoint and get the events data.

Here is the API:

```
https://www.newamerica.org/api/event/?time_period=past&page_size=12&page=1&story_image_rendition=small
```

This is how you can make a request and get the events data. This code prints `title` and `url` of each event in that page.

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.newamerica.org/api/event/?time_period=past&page_size=12&page=1&story_image_rendition=small'

r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()

for i in data['results']:
    title = i['title']
    link = i['url']
    print(f'Title: {title}\nURL: {link}\n\n')
```

```
Title: [ONLINE] - INSide Out: Youth-Led Policy in the Heartland
URL: /indianapolis/events/inside-out-youth-led-policy-in-the-heartland-3/

Title: [ONLINE] - Stretch Your Impact: Building Pathways Towards Tech for Good Careers
URL: /pit-un/events/online-stretch-your-impact-building-pathways-towards-tech-for-good-careers/

Title: [ONLINE] - Designing Accessible and Inclusive Digital Public Infrastructure
URL: /digital-impact-governance-initiative/events/designing-accessible-and-inclusive-digital-public-goods/
.
.
.
```